# what is the correct syntax for denying tcp connections to a subnet (cisco)?

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands

Is

`deny tcp any host 1.1.0.0 0.0.255.255`

correct,when I want to block access to the 1.1.0.0/16 subnet for any host on the LAN?

Comment: Cisco makes routers and firewalls which could potentially filter traffic.  Which product are you asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming it is an ASA/FWSM it is:

```
deny tcp any 1.1.0.0 255.255.0.0 [log]
```

The log portion is optional depending on the version being run. Specifying "host" would only be if you are going to specify access to be denied to a single host, for example:

```
deny tcp any host 1.1.1.1 [log]
```